# Express/EJS Array and List Click Appending

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ejs

Both the skills arrays are arrays of string I'm passing via Express, I want the list items to be clickable and when they are clicked I want the text (string) to be moved to the mySkills array variable that I also declared, as a blank array, and passed to the EJS file.

```
<ul>
    <% desSkills.forEach(function(e){ %>
        <li><%= e %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>

<ul>
    <% devSkills.forEach(function(e){ %>
        <li><%= e %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your `mySkills` array is declared only in your front-end and you will pass it to the back-end. Is that right?

Comment: @Tom that's correct yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that following this example:

**EJS file**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var arrDevSkills = [];
            function addDevSkills(value) {
                arrDevSkills.push(value);
                alert("Values: " + arrDevSkills);
            }

            var arrDesSkills = [];
            function addDesSkills(value) {
                arrDesSkills.push(value);
                alert("Values: " + arrDesSkills);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>DesSkills</h1>
    <ul>
        <% desSkills.forEach(function(e){ %>
            <li onclick="addDesSkills(<%= e %>);"><%= e %></li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>

    <h1>DevSkills</h1>
    <ul>
        <% devSkills.forEach(function(e){ %>
            <li onclick="addDevSkills(<%= e %>);"><%= e %></li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Clicking over the elements will make it work, if the elements are numbers or booleans.

In case you need the parameters to be a string, please add the single quote in the parameters passed to the JS function (e.g. `onclick="addDesSkills('<%= e %>');"`).

Hope it's somehow helpful.